What is the "proper form" of a symbiote?
In Venom: The Last Dance (2024), Venom must avoid showing his "proper form", which is explained as everything short of not having any more of the host visible(*).
He did not hesitate to take over the horse, though, and the codex was not detected.
Is the "proper form" always with a human host?

(*)which does not make much sense because there could be an uncovered 0.1 mm2 and everyone would be good
